# I'm unable to find configuration of pgAdmin4 on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, pgadmin-4

I'm new to PostgreSQL, just installed it along with pgAdmin4. After installation when I clicked on the pgAdmin4 it start in the browser of IE. But I want that in my chrome browser so I searched for it. Most of the people have mentioned or shared a picture of pgAdmin 4 configuration like this.

[image]

They mentioned it like *right click the icon in the Windows System Tray and select Configure* but the pgAdmin is not showing in the system tray of window 8.1. Or may be I'm misunderstanding about the system tray. Because in windows 8.1 pgAdmin 4 directly opens in browser.

*The browser issues is fixed by change by default browser to chrome* but I'm still unable to find this configuration setting. Can anyone help me to understand or get this screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pgAdmin 4 is a web server, so when you click pgAdmin 4 on the start menu, it starts the web server in the background, then opens a browser to connect to it.

The web server running in the background should have added a small icon to the system tray in the lower right corner.

On my Window 7 it looks like this:

[image: System Tray]

Comment: Great its worked for me. I was just misunderstanding the word system tray. On window 8.1 its look like the picture you shared.